# Format sqlite3 .schema command output

Tags: database, sqlite, python3

I created some sqlite tables schema using python. When I use the sqlite3 client and issue the .schema command, I can see the output is pre-formated as in the SQL source file I used as argument for the executescript() function.

Is there any method I can use to "auto-format" the SQL (as it is done in some IDE) of the output of the .schema command ?

I wonder if there is any way to do it directly inside the sqlite3 client, but I'm also interested in any tools or library (python3) to do so.

I know that the best thing I can do is nicely format the SQL myself but I also ask this for the case where the tables declaration were badly formatted and I still want to have a nicely formatted output when I issue the .schema command.